# Importing sknw on jupyter ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

On my jupyter notebook, running `import sknw` throws a `ModuleNotFoundError` error.

I have tried `pip install sknw` and `pip3 install sknw` and `python -m pip install sknw`. It appears to have downloaded successfully, and get `requirement already satisfied` if I try to download it again.

Any help on how to get the sknw package to work in jupyter notebook would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check on which environment you using pip.

Comment: What environment should I be in?

Comment: Are you using anaconda?

Comment: yes! im running a python3 file in a jupyter notebook

Comment: Open the notebook in Jupyter Notebooks and look in the upper right corner of the screen. Name should be the same in anaconda prompt

Comment: All I see is the box that says 'Trusted' and then Python 3.. :(

Comment: ok, how do you start jupyter-notebook? Via anaconda prompt? then u should see the name of enviroment on the left side in anaconda prompt in the brackets like: `(base) C:\Users\....`.  After that, check if you are using pip in the same environment as you are starting a jupiter notebook

Comment: If that's all, please close the question :)